# Redirecting not working properly in Firefox 9 (or any older version for that matter)

Tags: mod-rewrite, 301-redirect, firefox

How do I fix a redirect in Firefox so that it leads my site to another address but with a slash at the end of it?

This is my redirect in `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.mydomain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.test\.mydomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^testword$ "http\:\/\/outsidedomain\.com\/test\.mydomain\.com\/testword\/" [R=301,L]
```

It works fine in Chrome.

This is what it's suppose to do:

`test.mydomain.com/testword` should lead to `outsidedomain.com/test.mydomain.com/testword/`. Instead, in Firefox it leads to `outsidedomain.com/test.mydomain.com/testword`. Notice the lack of forward slash.

It has to have a slash at the end because otherwise the script from `outsidedomain.com` doesn't work properly.

**UPDATE:**
I'm using `http://nyanit.com` to display a page at my blog so when a user writes `mydomain.com/testword` it leads to `http://nyanit.com/mydomain.com/testword/`. It show's all right in Chrome where the "nyanit" script is loaded only once but in Firefox displaying that "testword" page starts a redirection again so the page doesn't show but only the sript is showing multiple times.

Check it out [here](http://india.thefalljourney.com/cat). Try both Chrome and Firefox to see what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic error, your rule only matches paths which *literally* match `/testword`. If you want to redirect everything that begins with `/testword`, remove the `$`:

```
RewriteRule ^testword "http\:\/\/outsidedomain\.com\/test\.mydomain\.com\/testword\/" [R=301,L]
```

If you want to match `/testword` and `/testword/` and nothing else, make the slash optional by adding `/?`:

```
RewriteRule ^testword/?$ "http\:\/\/outsidedomain\.com\/test\.mydomain\.com\/testword\/" [R=301,L]
```

---

It looks like that `nyanit.com` opens `http://india.thefalljourney.com/cat/` in your browser. Perhaps you're viewing a cached page in Chromium which is why the redirection is not infinite. The problem is:

- `http://india.thefalljourney.com/cat` is redirected to `http://nyanit.com/india.thefalljourney.com/cat/`
- `http://india.thefalljourney.com/cat/` is opened in a `<iframe>` by nyanit.com
- With the rewrite rule, `http://india.thefalljourney.com/cat/` is rewritten again... infinite loop.

Suggestion: don't use an Apache redirect for this, but Javascript. If it's detected that the page is in a frame, do not redirect. Put the below JS code on `http://india.thefalljourney.com/cat` and remove the apache redirection code:

```
<script>
if (parent == self) {
    location.replace("http://nyanit.com/india.thefalljourney.com/cat/");
}
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, you're solution is correct but there's obviously a problem with Firefox. When I redirect to `outsidedomain.com/test.mydomain.com/testword/`, Chrome shows the outside website's script correctly on top of the page from my site but Firefox starts an unlimited loop and loads an outside sripts more than once (indefinitely, actually). Is there a way to fix that? Check out the question update, please.

Comment: @rlesko See updated answer.

Comment: Works perfectly. The only problem now is that there is no sound in Chrome but I'm sure that has nothing to do with the redirect.
Doesn't matter actually, thanks for your help...